# How can I order in SQL with conditional statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

```
select *
from myaccount .....
order by t.Status, t.OpenDate, r.RegDate
```

In this case it is order by that three status, but I want to separate result with status

```
when status = 0
order by t.OpenDate,r.RegDate
```

and if other status, different from original statement that ordered by status, I want to mix status and only order by t.OpenDate,r.RegDate

How can I do this with conditional statement? I still keep try this, but I only find the way with one condition.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Your two ordering criteria are identical for all values of `status`.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Add some sample data, the question is a bit confusing at the minute without the context behind it. you may want to use a where clause for the date. as in..................... WHERE t.OpenDate >= r.regdate. Also as there are different alias' you must be joining tables, can you provide the full query... Many thanks

Comment: Maybe look at CTE? As Gordon said. Hard to see without linked data. Try http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: So rows with `status = 0` should come first, regardless of the `opendate` and the `regdate` and after that all rows with `status <> 0` should come, ordered by `opendate` then `regdate`?

Comment: Yes That's what exactly I mean

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `CASE` expression that returns a lower value when `status = 0` than it does for `status <> 0`.

```
...
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN t.status = 0 THEN
             0
           ELSE
             1
         END,
         t.opendate,
         r.regdate;
```

Comment: Or, in MySQL, just `order by (t.status = 0) desc, t.opendate, t.regdate`